# Excel compare corresponding values of the same index within two different columns

Tags: excel, indexing

I have a sheet containing four columns in total A, B, C, and D. Column A has the corresponding value in B and Column C has the corresponding value in D. I want to use a formula that basically compares each corresponding value of Col A with the corresponding value of Col C.

```
| A | B   | C | D    |
| 1 | 100 | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 3 | 3000 |
| 3 | 300 | 1 | 1000 |
```

The above shows that 100 is the corresponding value of index 1 and 1000 is the corresponding value of the same index but in another column. How can i list them next to each other depending on index like below please.

```
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 200 | 2 | 2000 |
```

This whole concept is then to match both corresponding values and see if they match or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sort numerically in columns A and C

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a very long list with the index in column A & C are not completely identical, then you can use vlookup() or index()+match() to create your table. Otherwise, just sort column C & D as Trauger suggested.